# Appium-Android-Unable to access elements after login to the account

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

```
driver.getContextHandles() - > [NATIVE_APP]
```

`capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);`

1)Added wait time. Manually logged in to the account.

`System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());` - prints the page source

Attaching success logs:-

```
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: []
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP"]
[W3C (afefcb31)] Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP"]
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/afefcb31-9574-4bf8-ba8a-fce9eb1e81a0/contexts 200 50 ms - 24
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/afefcb31-9574-4bf8-ba8a-fce9eb1e81a0/source
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (afefcb31)] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["afefcb31-9574-4bf8-ba8a-fce9eb1e81a0"]
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: source
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[AndroidBootstrap] Stream still not complete, waiting up to 60000ms for the data to arrive
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] [APPIUM-UIAUTO] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"<\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout>
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] " bounds=\"[0,280][1440,2196]\" resource-id=\"\" instance=\"4\"><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.TableRow><\/android.widget.TableLayout>
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] false\" clickable=\"false\" enabled=\"true\" focusable=\"false\" focused=\"false\" scrollable=\"false\" long-clickable=\"false\" password=\"false\" selected=\"false\" bounds=\"[0,471][1440,1237]\" resource-id=\"com.adaptavant.setmore:id\/compactcalendar_view\" instance=\"1\"\/><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout>
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] ant.setmore:id\/add_appointmenttv\" instance=\"14\"\/><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout>
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[AndroidBootstrap] Stream still not complete, waiting up to 60000ms for the data to arrive
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] droid.widget.LinearLayout\" package=\"com.adaptavant.setmore\" content-desc=\"\" checkable=\"false\" checked=\"false\" clickable=\"false\" enabled=\"true\" focusable=\"false\" focused=\"false\" scrollable=\"false\" long-clickable=\"false\" password=\"false\" selected=\"false\" bounds=\"[0,1584][1440,1769]\" resource-id=\"com.adaptavant.setmore:id\/noappt\" instance=\"14\"><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView><\/android.view.ViewGroup><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.FrameLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.FrameLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.FrameLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.FrameLayout>
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[AndroidBootstrap] Stream still not complete, waiting up to 60000ms for the data to arrive
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] se\" focused=\"false\" scrollable=\"false\" long-clickable=\"false\" password=\"false\" selected=\"false\" bounds=\"[0,2196][288,2392]\" resource-id=\"\" instance=\"17\"><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.RelativeLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.view.ViewGroup><\/android.widget.FrameLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.FrameLayout><\/android.widget.LinearLayout><\/android.widget.FrameLayout><\/hierarchy>"}[/APPIUM-UIAUTO]
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[W3C (afefcb31)] Responding to client with driver.getPageSource() result: "
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/afefcb31-9574-4bf8-ba8a-fce9eb1e81a0/source 200 216 ms - 48361
```

2) Logged in to the account(automation script), and try to print

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource()); - Appium is not responding.
```

Unable to identify elements inside the app.

Attaching the failure logs:-

```
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: []
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP"]
[W3C (3d562d17)] Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP"]
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3d562d17-697c-4bca-b4eb-c5d0dcd898d6/contexts 200 164 ms - 24
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3d562d17-697c-4bca-b4eb-c5d0dcd898d6/source
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3d562d17)] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["3d562d17-697c-4bca-b4eb-c5d0dcd898d6"]
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: source
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3d562d17-697c-4bca-b4eb-c5d0dcd898d6/source - - ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3d562d17-697c-4bca-b4eb-c5d0dcd898d6/source
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3d562d17)] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["3d562d17-697c-4bca-b4eb-c5d0dcd898d6"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, 'uiAutomator2');
```

Added the capability and it works now